# Firmware security

Tags: updates, firmware

I plan to experiment with firmware securities. What security mechanisms are there that prohibit me from plugging in my personal firmware. I do understand some devices might be powerful in terms of security, but technically speaking what is there to stop me from putting in my own firmware? (Only thing I can think of is, the compatibility of the firmware with the hardware)

What else should I worried or bothered about before developing my own version or reverse engineering one firmware?

Edit:
I want to put my own firmware in a smart watch. What security mechanisms is there that is stopping me to do it?

Comment: Firmware for what sort of device? The firmware for a router is going to be different from the firmware for a smartwatch, and will have different protections against modifications. I think this might be considered too broad in the current wording.

Comment: Firmwares on smart watch or any IoT. There are plenty of materials online about firmware on routers but for other devices there isn't much. It is only been told its insecure in a very vague terminology. I am really keen to know for what aspects it is. Like what security mechanisms are there that is stopping me to put my own firmware - lets say in a smartwatch. :)

Comment: Personally I would say smart watch and IoT falls into completely different categories. One is like a small computer that can run all kinds of software and speak all kinds of protocols and the other coud be very very dumb... The discussion would be quite different.

Comment: As asked, this question is too broad - you appear to want a collection of things to consider when developing firmware for any type of hardware. Secondly, this is more of a programming question than a security question because security measures in place on the hardware are only one small factor to consider.

Comment: @schroeder I believe the OP just wants to know what security companies place on hardware to ensure it cannot be tampered with or maybe to even prove it has been tampered with? for example when flashing an android phone it creates a flash counter which would void your warranty

Comment: @silverpenguin I see that but the scope is all IoT devices

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could rather point to any IoT devices they have knowledge about rather than discussing the problem in general repeatedly. Feel like I am in a loop reading the comments that I can foresee coming. Not helpful. Sad face.